# SSRS 2008 R2 - all parameters multi value AND optional

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, optional-parameters

I've got a report that has 6 parameters.  All parameters need to be optional and 3 have to be multi-value.  One of the optional parameters is a dropdown, the rest are manually keyed in text boxes. 
The Where clause below works when there are multiple @VendorNum values and one @FullJA value, but fails with multiple @FullJA values regardless of the @VendorNum count.

Parameters:
@VendorNum - keyed manually by user (space delimited) - optional, can be multivalue
@FullJA - keyed manually by user (space delimited) - optional, can be multivalue
@BU - optional, can be multivalue - when @JA is populated, this will auto-populate, if @JA isn't populated it's a dropdown with all selected.
@JA3 - keyed by user - optional, single value 
@StartDate and @EndDate - optional single values

```
    select * from some_table
    WHERE
    /*FULL JA*/
    (
        SUBSTRING(VendorNum, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', VendorNum    + '.'), LEN(VendorNum)
        ) IN (@VendorNum)
        AND LEFT(JA, 7) IN (@FullJA)
        AND BU IN(@BU)
        AND @JA3 IS NULL
        )
OR
    /*DATE RANGE*/
    (
        SUBSTRING(VendorNum, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', VendorNum + '.'), LEN(VendorNum)
        ) IN (@VendorNum)
        AND LEN(ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Cleared_When), '0')) >= @ClearedOnly
        AND ad.Audit_Publish_Date >= ISNULL(@StartDate, '2015-01-01')
        AND ad.Audit_Publish_Date <= ISNULL(@EndDate, '2025-12-31')
        AND BU IN (@BU)
        AND @FullJA IS NULL
        AND @JA3 IS NULL
        )

    /*BUS UNIT AND JA3*/
    OR (
        SUBSTRING(VendorNum, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', VendorNum + '.'), LEN(VendorNum)
        ) IN (@VendorNum)
        AND BU IN (@BU)
        AND ad.Audit_Publish_Date >= ISNULL(@StartDate, '2015-01-01')
        AND ad.Audit_Publish_Date <= ISNULL(@EndDate, '2025-12-31')
        AND LEFT(JA, 3) = (@JA3)
        AND @FullJA IS NULL
        )
    /*BUS UNIT ONLY*/
    OR (
        SUBSTRING(VendorNum, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', VendorNum + '.'), LEN(VendorNum)
        ) IN (@VendorNum)
        AND BU IN (@BU)
        AND ad.Audit_Publish_Date >= ISNULL(@StartDate, '2015-01-01')
        AND ad.Audit_Publish_Date <= ISNULL(@EndDate, '2025-12-31')
        AND @JA3 IS NULL
        AND @FullJA IS NULL
        )
```

The dataset parameter values for @FullJA and @VendorNum are both 
=IIF(InStr(Parameters!FullJA.Value," ")>0,SPLIT(Parameters!FullJA.Value," "),Parameters!FullJA.Value) and all params are set as NOT multivalue, with nulls allowed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've written over 200 reports for this project and this is the only one that is really grinding my gears!

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up creating a table for the values and populated them as you directed.  I stored them all in one table, then used aliases in the stored proc to grab the correct values from each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by building up some temp tables / table variables, to hold the potentially multi-valued variables, and then joining to those tables.  This has the advantage of you being able to insert all possible values, in the case they have omitted the variable.  So, you'd split your strings and put them into those tables (something along the lines of [this example](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html)) if given the variable, and otherwise just do an `insert into` to populate your temp table / table variable.

For a split function, I prefer something like this:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@sep VARCHAR(32), @s VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT r.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') as Item
        FROM (SELECT CONVERT(XML, N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@s,'& ','&amp; '),'<','&lt;'), @sep, '</r><r>') + '</r></root>') as valxml) x
        CROSS APPLY x.valxml.nodes('//root/r') AS RECORDS(r)
    )
GO
GRANT SELECT
    ON OBJECT::[dbo].[Split] TO PUBLIC
    AS [dbo];
```

I would then put those variables into a table using something like this (my separator is a ", "):

```
select ltrim(rtrim(ppl.Item)) as PersonName
into #gppl
from dbo.Split(', ', @PersonListForCompare) as ppl
```

You would do something more like:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(vnd.Item)) as VendorNum
into #vendorNums
from dbo.Split(', ', @VendorNum) as vnd
```

You would then join to that temp table just like any other table & use it to limit your results that way.  In your case, you want to put in all vendors (possibly) if they didn't give you any input.  So, you'd do something like:

```
create table #vendorNums (VendorName varchar(64))   --I have no idea, here, what this data looks like

if @VendorNum is not null and datalength(@VendorNum) > 0
    insert into into #vendorNums (VendorNum)
    select ltrim(rtrim(vnd.Item))
    from dbo.Split(', ', @VendorNum) as vnd
else
    insert into into #vendorNums (VendorNum)
    select VendorNum
    from dbo.Vendors
```

That said, I think that you could use your `select from dbo.Split` directly as a table in a join, rather than putting it into the temp table.  Only problem would be you'd have to be sure you had data in there *to* split, or else you're going to have a bunch of combinations to get the right match-up of null parameters vs. filled ones.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding...I've not got much experience with stored procs and temp tables. Is it possible to create this kind of report without them?  I have used the split functionality on other reports but when I tried it with this report the query would run in SSMS but SSRS would error with the "udf.split function has too many arguments".  That is how I ended up with the split function in the dataset parameters.

Comment: @tardytrtl Just edited - have another look & see if it's clearer.

Comment: That is much clearer; thank you for the additional detail.  I will give this a try.

Comment: @tardytrtl Do let everybody know how you solved it, whether or not my solution helped, so that this can help someone else down the road some time. :)

Comment: I ended up creating a table for the values and populated them as you directed.  I stored them all in one table, then used aliases in the stored proc to grab the correct values from each column.

Comment: Awesome! If mine is the right answer, you could accept it as the answer. Thanks!